# Plotting co-ordinates on python - what data type to use?

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates

I'm working on a task that involves isolating information from a CSV document (to be specific, the timestamp in nanoseconds and the latitude and longitude). I have managed to print these values successfully, but now I would like to plot it using matplotlib. This is my code so far:

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

midnight = 1429574400
nsmidnight = 1429574400000000000
ifile  = open('(short file)Converted_radar_tracks_20150421_053822.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.DictReader(ifile, delimiter=';')

rownum = 0

for row in reader:#for each row
    if rownum == 0:
        header = row #define header row
    else:
        print "Timestamp:", long(row['timestamp'])*1000000000+nsmidnight+ int(row['timestamp_nsecs']),"Latitude:", float(row['lat']), "Longitude:", float(row['lon'])
        plt.plot('lat','lon')

    rownum += 1

plt.show()
ifile.close
```

However, when I run it, I get this error message:

```
ValueError: Unrecognized character l in format string
```

I think it may be because I am using the wrong data type for latitude and longitude. Does anyone have any suggestions to help me?

Comment: Please post the stack trace for your error message.

Comment: Usually, you'll accumulate the latitude and longitude points in a list.  Once the entire lists are built, you pass them to `plt.plot`.

Comment: You are mixing int with long. Perhaps this should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `plt.plot('lat','lon')`, it is trying to plot the string `lat` with a format string `lon`. This does not work and gives you the error you see. What `plt.plot()` wants as arguments are lists of latitudes and longitudes. For example,

```
lat = [13, 26, 48]
lon = [51, 17, 19]
plt.plot(lat, lon)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`plt.plot()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) takes a list or array of x and y pairs, not strings as you are passing with `plt.plot('lat', 'lon')`. The ValueError you are getting is due to this. Instead, put your values for latitude and longitude into a list  or numpy array first, then pass them to `plt.plot()` like so:

```
lat = [41, 42, 43, 44, 45]
lon = [70, 71, 72, 73, 74]
plt.plot(lat, lon)
```